# Javah class access fail

Tags: android, android-ndk

I wanna use tesseract library with my application so i need to implement ndk.i download it add its path to my bash_profile.

```
export ANDROID_ADB=/Users/gokhanaliccii/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
export ANDROID_NDK=/android_ndk/android-ndk-r10d
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_ADB:$ANDROID_NDK
```

My problem is appeared when i run -javah command at studio terminal. My command is

```
javah -d jni -classpath /Users/gokhanaliccii/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-19/android.jar:/Users/gokhanaliccii/Documents/gokhan_private/android_ocr/NDK_TEST/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug gokhanaliccii.kou.ndk_test.MainActivity
```

[image: step 1]

after i got this error i tried to add support libraries
[image: step 2]

I tried to solved it but i coulndt find solution i'm really exhausted i hope someone know how to solve it

My project is at /Users/gokhanaliccii/Documents/gokhan_private/android_ocr/NDK_TEST

Comment: Take a look at this related StackOverflow question: [javah Android Studio Error: cannot access android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27201775/javah-android-studio-error-cannot-access-android-support-v7-app-actionbaractivi)

Comment: I have already added it (I showed it in second photo) @JonnyHenly

Answer (score 0):

Dont need cp for javah

Run javac on source that includes file with native headers.

Cd to path that is parent of the root of where the ".class" files are.

On cli or in terminal run the javah ( no cp needed )

If stuvk do the ndk samples and it will make sense . They walk u thru javah sample

Comment: I watched http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=okLKfxfbz40&index=3&list=WL  and started to apply my example it is too easy I only added native String getString(); and run my javah command @Robert Rowntree

Answer (score 0):

After lot of researches and training i solved my problem.

```
javah  -classpath /Users/gokhanaliccii/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-19/android.jar:/Users/gokhanaliccii/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/libs/android-support-v4.jar:/Users/gokhanaliccii/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar:../../build/intermediates/classes/debug -d jni gokhanaliccii.kou.ndk_test.MainActivit
```

My result command is above.I tried it at android studio,classes files are at build/intermediadtes/classes/debug if you want try it at eclipse it is under bin folder.