# Error: cannot access android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-ndk

I need your help, (I searched the questions, but I do not understand though the answers are positive) What should insert code? (The answer comes that I send the code of appcompatactivity. But I do not understand)

I'm working with android NDK but send me the error .. This is my code

```html
C:\Users\Eduu\AndroidStudioProjects\NDKSample2\app\src\main>javah -d jni classpath C:\Users\Eduu\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar;..\..\build\intermediates\classes\debug com.example.eduu.ndksample2.MainActivity
```

work: Android Studio

Comment: Please revise your question. The `javah` command seems to have nothing to do with **android.support.v7**. Please post the full error message.

Comment: Achieve progress, but does not send me error.  http://prntscr.com/8wk7hm

--Code--
javah -d jni -classpath C:\Users\Eduu\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar;C:\Users\Eduu\AppData\Loc
al\Android\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\libs\android-support-v7-appcompat.jar;C:\Users\Eduu\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\libs\android-supp
ort-v4.jar;C:\Users\Eduu\AndroidStudioProjects\NDKSample2\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug com.example.eduu.ndksample2.MainActivity

Comment: I use the tutorial is as follows: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=okLKfxfbz40

Comment: and here I found an appropriate response but it was me ... because I do not believe anything.   -->http://prntscr.com/8wk969 Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27201775/javah-android-studio-error-cannot-access-android-support-v7-app-actionbaractivi

Comment: solved. I had not seen but had already been created. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a new app, Eclipse gives you a copy of the compatibility library. (One can only guess if you are using Eclipse, but I do.) The purpose of this library is to implement fragments and other post-3.0 stuff on 2.x devices. You are given this library only if you specify a 2.x target when you create the project. In one of my workspaces, I have 24 copies of the library, ranging from `appcompat_v7` to `appcompat_v7_24`. Each one is located on the same directory level as the corresponding project, that is, in the same parent folder. It is easy to guess which copy corresponds to the latest project, but if you don't know for sure that the project is the latest one, you have to search the config files.

If you put your project under version control and forget about this dependency, you get an error in the copy retrieved from the version control. Fixing it is a tedious task, Eclipse is no lucid coding. You will have to manually specify the dependency in several places. One possible approach is to create a new project and move the source to it (note that you can move the version control directory, like `.hg` or `.git`, and restore the source, if that does not sound too untrivial for you), another one is to create a new project and use its compatibility library.

Comment: job Android Studio.. but progress. I just do not send anything and does not create anything. http://prntscr.com/8wk7hm...

    
I use the tutorial is as follows: youtube.com/watch?v=okLKfxfbz40 
     
and here I found an appropriate response but it was me ... because I do not believe anything. -->prntscr.com/8wk969 Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27201775/javah-android-studio-error-cannot-access-android-support-v7-app-actionbaractivi

Comment: solved. I had not seen but had already been created. Thank you!